# Datatable is working but redirects to undefined page when page is clicked

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsp, datatables, bootstrap-4

My datatable works but when i click another page of the table, it redirects the page to "undefined" page which does not exist. When i click a page number, it briefly shows the correct result but then it gets redirected to the "undefined" page.

jquery

```
$('#branchtables').DataTable( {
     "pagingType": "full_numbers",
       "paging": true,

} );
```

HTML

```
<table id = "branchtables" class="table table-borderless table-data3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Partner ID</th>
            <th>Partner Name</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Parent DSP</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <core:forEach var="data" items="${partners}" varStatus="count" >
            <tr id="removetable">

                <core:choose>
                <core:when test = "${data.parentid eq PID}">
                    <td id="removetable" class="tablefonts mytablewidth"><a href="managebranches?pid=${data.branchid}">${data.branchid}</a></td>
                </core:when>
                <core:otherwise>
                    <td id="removetable" class="tablefonts mytablewidth">${data.branchid}</td>
                </core:otherwise>
                </core:choose>

                <td id="removetable" class="tablefonts mytablewidth">${data.branchname}</td>
                <td id="removetable" class="tablefonts mytablewidth">${data.email}</td>
                <td id="removetable" class="tablefonts mytablewidth">${data.parentpartner}</td>

            </tr>
        </core:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

data table links

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>  
   <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
  </script>
```

Comment: what is `href=/cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css` ? use `http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The body has a class `<body class="animsition">`i just removed the class and it worked. IT seems like the bootstrap body does not work well with the datatable.